# How to run if condition only on certain columns in awk

Tags: linux, awk

I have a file with columns as shown below:

```
row1  0.15  0.03
row2  0.06  0.028
row3  0.05  0.05
row4    
row5        0.09    
row6
```

I want to filter the file by removing rows if values in col2=col3. This is quiet simple condition to write '$2=$3'. But, when $2=$3 condition is applied, rows with blank values in col2 and col3 are also filtered. I would like this condition to be run on only rows which has values. Sample output shown below. Only row 3 is filtered. Even though also meets the condition it does not have any integer values.

```
row1  0.15  0.03
row2  0.06  0.028
row4    
row5        0.09    
row6
```

I know it is something simple but it does not work when i tried in the below way and also few other ways, it prints the original file.

```
awk -F '\t' '$1!="" && $2!= "" {$1==$2}1' OFS="\t"
```

Comment: Your main problem is that `{$1==$2}` is executing a comparison inside the action block so the result of that comparison is not being tested as a condition and so has no effect. always remember that awk is made up of `<condition> { <action> }` statements so you meant something like `$1==$2 { print }`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With awk:

```
awk -F '\t' -v OFS='\t' '$2 == "" || $2 != $3' filename
```

- The code `$2 == "" || $2 != $3` is just a condition, so the default action (printing) is performed if it is true.
- An explicit check for `$3 == ""` is not necessary because either `$2 == ""` or `$2 != $3` is true in that case.